# A program that can press keys

Tags: hotkeys

I would like to know if there's a program that can press keys. For instance I would like the program to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> and <kbd>Print Screen</kbd>. I have googled a bit and found out that notepad can do this but I dont seem to get it right.

Answer (score 6):

[AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: I downloaded AutoHotKey but I dont know what must be inside the script. Please include the exact text to press keys, with spaces so i can add my keys to the script.

Comment: @user6321; The documentation is very good and can explain it far better than I can, but the jist of it is that `LHS::RHS` maps the key on the left hand side to the sequence on the right hand side. For example, `q::^v{PrintScreen}` would press control-v, then printscreen, when you press the q button.

Answer (score 0):

Theres [ACTool](http://www.actool.net/) for example. It was made for a game (Asheron's Call) but it works with anything else, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to write a script to automate key presses, try [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/).  It is its own scripting language but can act as a plugin to vbscript & powershell

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [Jaex/Automate](//github.com/Jaex/Automate). It is open source and has an easy
interface:

> [image: GUI]